# Getting 240VAC output from 220-230VAC input

Tags: mains, test-equipment

For lab testing at work I need to be able to test an appliance (often more than 3KW, e.g. deep fryers and waffle irons) at 240VAC. The problem is that our power grid only provides between 220 and 230 VAC.

So I'm looking for the best way to get a steady 240VAC output from a slightly variable input (we're in an industrial area).

A variable output would be nice, but is not a requisite.

Any help/hints/direction would be more than welcome!

Comment: Find a transformer. Like n=1.1. Maybe two transfotmers.

Comment: If the input on a transformer varies, so does the output. I'm looking for something that outputs 240VAC, regardless of input variation.

Comment: Then rectifier and inverter

Comment: I thought of that, but I worry about resonance between the two. Or do I worry about that needlessly?

Comment: You have nothing to worry about. Justbdo it carefully and safely

Comment: A motor driven generator should isolate the output from line variations. Or maybe consider 240v power inverter.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be considering using a decent UPS - it can provide a stable output and a decent sine wave with variable input voltage conditions. You must choose one that always converts the input to DC and then uses an inverter to generate the output voltage. Some UPS designs will pass through the input AC voltage and only "switch in" the backup system when there is a power fail. These types are not sufficient for your needs.

Maybe one of [these](https://novaelectric.com/product/3-kva-15-kva-pulsar-series-true-online-ups/) and the giveaway is that they can output 50 or 60 Hz irrespective of the input frequency - this tells you that they are true inverting converters.

Comment: These are known as "online UPS" or "double conversion UPS".

Comment: @OskarSkog yes, the one I linked is an online type.

Answer (score 2):

Get a [Variac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer#Variable_autotransformers) (more accurately; a variable auto-transformer).

[image]
[image]

These devices are usually made for stepping *down* mains AC, but many have a slight "overdrive as well". A common range seems to be 1 : 0-1.1. They are available for reasonable prices up to several kilowatts.

Comment: The output will fluctuate when the input does, I'm looking for something that stays exactly at 240VAC, regardless of variation in input.

Comment: @DaJF Ah yeah, a variac doesn't do that for you. Is your mains supply really that variable?

Comment: We're in an industrial area, so when a big power user switches on or off, it can fluctuate a little.

Answer (score 0):

The most convenient old-skool way to do it is to use an auto-transformer, followed by a step-down transformer. As you want 3kW loads, it's worth doing this two-stage approach.

For instance, a 2A autotransformer followed by a 500VA 20V fixed transformer would allow you to vary the incoming mains voltage by up to +/- 20v, at an output current of 25A.

To do that directly from an autotransformer, you would need a 25A version.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Could you provide a schematic, and 2. Is there a way the output could be adjusted automatically, so it stays at 240VAC?

Answer (score 0):

For these kind of tests, especially if you are doing verification and not just happy tests (so there is a test report and the result must be reproducible), I suggest buying professional testing equipment.

There are variable AC power supplies around from several companies. Most of them allow you to change the frequency as well, which might be a useful feature for some appliances.

They are quite costly (starting at 5k with 3kVA), but will regulate frequency and voltage very well.

Companies which should provide good stuff: EA (Elektro-Automatik, not Electronic Arts), Elettrotest, Chroma, Keysight and surely some more.